# How to get the common values from 2 Laravel collections

Tags: php, laravel, multidimensional-array, collections, unique

I have 2 Collections in Laravel, and I want only common values in my `$result` object. I see that `$collection->intersect()` works only for 1D array.
Below are the collections

```
Collection {#1086 ▼
  #items: array:5 [▼
    0 => {#1115 ▼
      +"name": "Light"
      +"class": "ABC"
      +"id": 4
    }
    1 => {#1113 ▼
      +"name": "Milo"
      +"class": "XYZ"
      +"id": 10
    }
    2 => {#1120 ▼
      +"name": "Milo Test"
      +"class": "ABC"
      +"id": 12
    }
    3 => {#1102 ▼
      +"name": "KMSMiloCow"
      +"class": "ABC"
      +"id": 16
    }
    4 => {#1106 ▼
      +"name": "MiloCows"
      +"class": "XYZ"
      +"id": 18
    }
  ]
}

Collection {#1086 ▼
      #items: array:5 [▼
        0 => {#1115 ▼
          +"name": "Light"
          +"class_name": "ABC"
          +"id": 4
        }           
      ]
    }
```

Now in my result, I just need this

```
Collection {#1086 ▼
          #items: array:5 [▼
            0 => {#1115 ▼
              +"name": "Light"
              +"class": "ABC"
              +"id": 4
            }           
          ]
        }
```

Comment: First you can merge both collection using "$array_merge = array_merge(collection1,collection2)"... After check "$array_unique = array_unique(array_column($array_merge, 'id'))"; and then after "array_intersect_key($array_merge, $array_unique);"

Comment: This gives me a merged array, not only the common values

Comment: then after apply "$array_unique = array_unique(array_column($array_merge, 'id'));"

Comment: Can you please write an answer to this so that I can test?

Comment: @Manisha to merge collection there is `$colleciton1->merge($collection2)` in laravel

Comment: @baig772 you may like to run a `map`, `each` collection method to make the intersect recursive.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu can you please explain this in an answer?

Comment: @baig772 may be my answer can give you some idea, check it and let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using collection method `each` and `contains`, it can be done like this

```
    $collection1->each(function ($value, $key) use ($collection2){
        return $collection2->contains($value);
    });
    dd($collection1);
```

I test it in routes file web.php like

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
Route::get('test', function(){
    $collection1 = new Collection([
        'bear',
        'whale',
        'chicken',
        'tardigrade'
    ], [[
        'bear8',
        'whale44',
        'chicken45',
        'tardigrade445'
    ]]);
    $collection2 = new Collection([
        'bear1',
        'whale2',
        'chicken3',
        'tardigrade4'
    ], [[
        'bear',
        'whale',
        'chicken',
        'tardigrade'
    ]]);
    $collection1->each(function ($value, $key) use ($collection2){
        return $collection2->contains($value);
    });
    dd($collection1);
});
```

Comment: This returns all elements from `$collection1` I only need the common ones

Comment: @baig772 if you can notice, first collection 1st array is same to second array in second collection and my code is returning that common array as result set, this is not returning `$collection1`, which has 2 elements, it is returning only one element which is common.

Comment: Not sure why this answer is accepted.. No matter what, this will return the first `array` from `$collection1`, NOT common elements. And for some reason you have nested arrays as second elements in both collections, which makes no sense. 
For this purpose ("real" Collections) you should use filter(), reject() etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea this would help you or not but these will be useful

```
$common_collection = $collection_1->whereIn('id', $collection_2->pluck('id')->toArray())
    ->unique('id')
    ->sortBy('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a collection with common elements, you can use [filter()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-filter):

> The filter method filters the collection using the given callback, keeping only those items that pass a given truth test

```
$commonCollection = $collection1->filter(function ($value, $key) use ($collection2){
    return $collection2->contains($value);
});
```

Comment: Using PHP7.4 arrow functions this can shortened to: `$commonCollection = $collection1->filter(fn ($item): bool => $collection2->contains($item));`

Answer (score 0):

use intersect https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-intersect

for example:

```
$commonValues = $collection1->pluck("id")->intersect($collection2->pluck("id"));

dd($commonValues);
```

Then get common collections

```
dd($collection1->whereIn("id", $commonValues));
```

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
 $a1 = array(
           array('name' => 'asdfjkl;', 'class' => 'foo'),
           array('name' => 'qwerty', 'class' => 'bar'),
           array('name' => 'uiop', 'class' => 'baz'),
        );
$a2 = array(
           array('name' => 'asdfjklk;', 'class' => 'foo'),
           array('name' => 'qwertyxs', 'class' => 'bar'),
           array('name' => 'uiop', 'class' => 'baz'),
        );
$cc = array_uintersect($a1, $a2, 'cmp');
print_r($cc);

function cmp($a1, $a2){
   return strcasecmp($a1['name'] , $a2['name']);
}
```